# Assembly language scanning long string for count of vowels

Tags: c++, arrays, string, assembly, inline-assembly

I am trying to scan my string below for vowels and increment their count. However, it is giving me break and unhandled exception errors. It seems to return just the number of the first vowel (a) in the string. The total number of vowels should be 491.

```
// Calculated Values: 492 total vowel counter.
//


#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
//  your properly formatted assembly language data here
char Decl[] = "We hold these truths to be self-evident, that "
              "all men are created equal, that they are "
              "endowed by their Creator with certain "
              "unalienable Rights, that among these are "
              "Life, Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness. "
              "That to secure these rights, Governments are "
              "instituted among Men, deriving their just "
              "powers from the consent of the governed, "
              "That whenever any Form of Government becomes "
              "destructive of these ends, it is the Right of "
              "the People to alter or to abolish it, and to "
              "institute new Government, laying its foundation "
              "on such principles and organizing its powers in "
              "such form, as to them shall seem most likely to "
              "effect their Safety and Happiness. Prudence, "
              "indeed, will dictate that Governments long "
              "established should not be changed for light and "
              "transient causes; and accordingly all epxerience "
              "hath shewn, that mankind are more disposed to "
              "suffer, while evils are sufferable, than to "
              "right themselves by abolishing the forms to "
              "which they are accustomed. But when a long train "
              "of abuses and usurpations, pursuing invariably "
              "the same Object evinces a design to reduce them "
              "under absolute Despotism, it is their right, "
              "it is their duty, to throw off such Government "
              "and to provide new Guards for their future "
              "security. Such has been the patient sufferance "
              "of these Colonies; and such is now the "
              "necessity which constrains them to alter their "
              "former Systems of Government. The history of "
              "the present King of Great Britain is a history "
              "of repeated injuries and usurpations, all "
              "having in direct object the establishment of "
              "an absolute Tyranny over these States. To "
              "prove this, let Facts be submitted to a "
              "candid world. Entered by Thomas Berny ";

char Vowels[] = "aeiouAEIOU";
unsigned short int TotalVowels = 0;

     __asm {
//  your syntatically correct assembly language code here
//  column alignment markers below (to guide you)
//      |       |               |
        mov     esi, 0          ;clear esi index register
check1: cld                     ;set left to right scan
        lea     edi, Decl       ;location of string to scan
        mov     cx, 1649        ;number of chars to scan +1
        mov     al, Vowels[esi] ;particular vowels
more1:
repne   scasb                   ;scan byte by byte
        cmp     cx, 0           ;see if end of string
        je      nocnt1          ;if so, dont increment counter
        inc     TotalVowels     ;otherwise increment
nocnt1: cmp     cx, 0           ;see if end of string
        ja      more1           ;if not, continue scanning
        inc     esi             ;point to next vowel
        cmp     esi, 10         ;done all vowels?
        jl      check1          ;if not, do another

    }
        cout << "The number of vowels is: " << TotalVowels;
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the second cmp cx,0: if you've incremented TotalVowels, you know you're not at the end of the string, and can jump to more1 w/o the comparison; if the first cmp says you're at the end of the string, jump straight to inc esi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ecx` instead of `cx`. You're leaving the top 16 bits of ecx uninitialized, and `rep scasb` does not stop at the intended end of string, instead goes on and on and on...

Comment: wow i knew it was a simple size issue. thanks. it works, however it does stop I think because it only repeats until cx = 0. cx, or rather ecx is decremented each time

Comment: My trusty Intel manual says that in 32-bit mode, specifically ECX is used by the REPxx prefix family.